# Building good-designed database for a simple webapp with NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm from SQL world, so please, don't ask me that there are no tables, relations, etc in NoSQL, I know it, but it's difficult for me to understand how I can keep news in categories without relations.

So, imagine that we want to keep in database news, categories for news, tags, user profiles and comments for news by users. With SQL I think that this task can be solved with architecture like this (don't look at syntax, it is pseudocode):

```
categories ( id, title )
news (id, title, content, category_id)
users (id, first_name, last_name, homepage_url)
news_comments (id, news_id, user_id, comment)
tags (id, title)
news_tags (news_id, tag_id)
```

How this task can be solved with MongoDB / CouchDB / NoSQL? I'm interested in good architecture, I don't need to know about something specific like indexes.

Comment: You probably need to narrow the question down to a single database, you're unlikely to get an exhaustive answer for every flavour of nosql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to denormalize your data. Your "news" record would look like:

```
news (id, title, content, category_title, [tags]) # that is list of tags
```

or technically more precise, something like:

```
(id, type=news, title, content, category_title, [tags])
```

You can filter by "foreign key" so having

```
news_comments (id, news_id, user_id, comment)
```

is not much of an issue if you want to select comments for a given news, but if you want to display user's `first_name` you would probably want to include that data in comment record itself.

So what if user changes it's data after commenting?

1. you don't really care
2. you are using wrong tool for a job

there is an option 3 you find all comments and update them, but if that's common enough case, you probably need relational database to begin with.